# Invalid resource directory name for values with country code

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an android app in more languages.
If I have a folder named: **values-en** I have no error and everything is working fine.

If I rename the name of the dir to **values-en_GB** i got this error: `android-apt-compiler: [NAMEOFAPP] invalid resource directory name: [path]\res/values-en_GB`

Why is this invalid? or what I should do to have for same language (in this example en) different values depend of the location (in this example US or GB)

I am using Idea 12, Java 1.7, Android 4.2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The format of your directory is incorrect. See: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Use:

```
res/values-en-rGB
```

Basically:

> The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code, optionally followed by a two letter ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 region code (preceded by lowercase "r").
>
> The codes are not case-sensitive; the r prefix is used to distinguish
>   the region portion. You cannot specify a region alone.

Comment: Thank you. Now is working. I am having another problem with Serbian language because I want 2 versions for Serbian: Cyrilic and Latin . Do you think it's posible ? I try something like this: value-sr-rRS-Latn but it's not working.  Thank you

Comment: @DaniDudas I don't think it is, sorry.

Comment: amazingly, the `r` was not mandatory in gradle 1.0.0, but is in gradle 1.3.1